# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Dockware

Tags: docker, macos, redirect, shopware6, docker-desktop

I have a very strange problem in my Shopware 6 Installation. I set up a completely new local Shopware 6 Installation with Dockware. This is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:

    shopware:
      image: dockware/dev:latest
      container_name: shopware
      ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "3306:3306"
         - "22:22"
         - "8888:8888"
         - "9999:9999"
         - "9998:9998"
      volumes:
        - "db_volume:/var/lib/mysql"
        - "shop_volume:/var/www/html"
      networks:
         - web
      environment:
         - XDEBUG_ENABLED=1
         - PHP_VERSION=8.1
volumes:
  db_volume:
    driver: local
  shop_volume:
    driver: local
networks:
  web:
    external: false
```

I can log into the backend and also access the frontend (http://localhost) without problems. But every category I try to open results in a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error with a 301 statuscode. The standard pages like the cart are no problem, only categories and landing pages.
As I said it's a clean installation without any custom config.
I'm running Docker Desktop on MacOS.

EDIT:
I just found out, that the error only occurs when a category has an SEO URL. I switched the language of the domain url in the storefront and the categories work but only without seo url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in shopware 6.5.8.0 and got fixed in 6.5.8.1

[Source](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/v6.5.8.1/changelog/release-6-5-8-1/2024-01-17-fix-redirect-loop.md)

Comment: I have just seen the fix. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).